# Coldfusion dynamic column names to pass into a function

Tags: coldfusion

A user can supply answers for up to 5 question, and each question has 3 columns in the database:

```
st_m1_id
st_m1_fam
st_m1_cip
st_m2_id
st_m2_fam
st_m2_cip
```

etc

When the form is submitted I get the IDs into an array and then loop over that and then query a different table to look up fam and cip.

```
aidms = listToArray(form['idms[]']);
  for( i=1;i<=arrayLen(aidms);i++ ) {
    qryData = invoke(dataCFC,'queryData', { smid = aidms[i]});

    temp = invoke(userCFC,'updateUser',{
      userid = session.userid,
      st_m#i#_id = aidms[i], 
      st_m#i#_fam = qryData.fam,
      etc......
    });

  };
```

How do I notate the dynamic query column names in the function so that when they are passed to updateUser the correct columns are referenced?

Comment: Similar column names, like Foo1,Foo2,...FooN are usually a sign the database needs to be restructured and [normalized](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A better approach is storing each set of responses as rows in a separate table - NOT columns.

Comment: @Ageax - 1000% agreed.  However that's not going to happen at the moment and I'm stuck with this for at least the next several months.

Comment: Ugh.. that'll cause a lot more headaches (and wasted time) than needed. Not sure I follow the format of the structure of submitted FORM values. Could you give an example?

Comment: Another option is to store the answers in a single column as JSON

Comment: Can you put your values into a struct and pass it as `ArgumentsCollection` into the invoke function? `struVVals = {}; struVals[ "st_m#i#_id" ] = aidms[i]` etc.

Comment: Also, any time you have to loop over a query, you should probably go back and see if you can do it without a loop. Each loop makes a connection to the database and can become very expensive. And can you provide an example of the form? Why do you need to process a comma-delimited list?

Comment: NOTE: I would also look out for Injection issues in this query. And I think it should also be mentioned that if you're regularly looping, you'd probably want to instantiate the CFC first and then loop the function rather than `cfinvoke` on each loop. And last, do you need 2 different database calls to `dataCFC` and `userCFC`? If you're querying the db for data that you're going to submit right back into the db, you can make one trip to join that data inside your queries.